# VS 2012: Sorting .CPP/.H files

Tags: visual-studio-2012

Is there a way that I can automatically sort a list of functions written in VS2012. 
at the moment it is:

```
void z(){}
int a(){}
int x(){}
int aa(){}
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Visual Assist X is an addon that lets you you drag and drop functions in the sidebar.  It's not free but it's really nice and arrr matey

An alternative would be to write a script that does the sorting for you if you always want it in alphabetical order.

Comment: Was looking for an Open source one for preference